# Android Studio - NFC Write Password

Tags: java, android-studio, nfc

estoy desarrollando una aplicación para escritura/lectura de NFC con Android Studio. El problema viene cuando quiero protegerlo contra escritura con una contraseña.

He visto en varios lugares que hablan de NdefFormatable pero esa clase siempre me devuelve null, entiendo que es porque la tecnología de mi etiqueta es NFC-A.

He intentado aplicar la contraseña en NFC-A con este código:

```
private void lockNfcTag(Tag tag, String password) {
NfcA nfcA = NfcA.get(tag);
try {
    nfcA.connect();
    byte[] passwordBytes = password.getBytes();
    byte[] lockBytes = new byte[4];
    System.arraycopy(passwordBytes, 0, lockBytes, 0, Math.min(passwordBytes.length, 4));
    byte[] response = nfcA.transceive(new byte[]{
            (byte) 0xA2,  // Write block command
            0x2F,  // Block number
            lockBytes[0], lockBytes[1], lockBytes[2], lockBytes[3],  // Data bytes
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Padding bytes
    });
    if (response != null && response.length >= 1) {
        if (response[0] == (byte) 0x00) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Etiqueta NFC bloqueada exitosamente.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error al bloquear la etiqueta NFC.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error al bloquear la etiqueta NFC.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error al bloquear la etiqueta NFC.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} finally {
    try {
        nfcA.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

El problema aquí es que en la linea "byte[] response = nfcA.transceive" me dice "Tag lost". Llamo este método nada más detectarlo así que no es un problema de haberlo movido.

He probado también MifareUltralight y pasa más o menos lo mismo:

```
private void protectWithTagPassword(MifareUltralight mifareUltralight, String password) throws IOException {
    // 1. Conectar a la etiqueta
    mifareUltralight.connect();

    // 2. Escribir la contraseña en la página de la memoria de la etiqueta (dónde se almacena la contraseña)
    byte[] passwordBytes = password.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    mifareUltralight.writePage(0x20, passwordBytes);

    // 3. Habilitar la protección de la etiqueta con contraseña usando el comando de autenticación
    byte[] authCommand = new byte[] {
            (byte) 0xA2, // Comando de escritura
            (byte) 0x22, // Dirección de la página de configuración
            (byte) 0x00, // Configuración de protección: habilitar protección con contraseña
            (byte) 0x00, // Byte de configuración adicional
            (byte) 0x00, // Byte de configuración adicional 2
            (byte) 0x00  // Byte de configuración adicional 3
    };
    mifareUltralight.transceive(authCommand);

    // 4. Desconectar de la etiqueta
    mifareUltralight.close();
}
```

En la linea mifareUltralight.writePage(0x20, passwordBytes); salta la Excepción Tag was lost

En cualquier caso alguien sabe la solución o otros métodos para hacerlo? Ante todo gracias